# How to throw an error in closure?

Tags: error-handling, swift2

My function:

```
func post(params: AnyObject, completion: (response : AnyObject ) -> Void) {


}
```

but I need something like Error throwing inside completion block

```
func post(params: AnyObject, completion: (response : **throws ->** AnyObject ) -> Void) {


}
```

so that I can **handle errors inside block itself**.

Answer (score 2):

It is small example how it is possible throw an error in closure.

First set up error enum:

```
enum TestError : ErrorType {
    case EmptyName
    case EmptyEmail
}
```

Than youre function should throw errors:

```
func loginUserWithUsername(username: String?, email: String?) throws -> String {
    guard let username = username where username.characters.count != 0 else {
        throw TestError.EmptyName
    }

    guard let email = email where email.characters.count != 0 else {
        throw TestError.EmptyEmail
    }

    return username
}
```

Than create block for calling it:

```
func asynchronousWork(completion: (inner: () throws -> TestError) -> Void) -> Void {
    do {
        try loginUserWithUsername("test", email: "")
    } catch let error {
        completion(inner: {throw error})
    }
}
```

Handle errors like it:

```
asynchronousWork { (inner: () throws -> TestError) -> Void in
    do {
        let result = try inner()
    } catch TestError.EmptyName {
        print("empty name")
    } catch TestError.EmptyEmail {
        print("empty email")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In case you would like to use rethrows this code example was taken from this [link](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2015/06/closures-that-throw-rethrows-in-swift-20.html):

```
enum NumberError:ErrorType {
    case ExceededInt32Max
}

func functionWithCallback(callback:(Int) throws -> Int) rethrows {
    try callback(Int(Int32.max)+1)
}

do {
    try functionWithCallback({v in if v <= Int(Int32.max) { return v }; throw NumberError.ExceededInt32Max})
}
catch NumberError.ExceededInt32Max {
    "Error: exceeds Int32 maximum"
}
catch {
}
```

Comment: you can use rethrows for that